# select statement for a field inside another select statement - oracle

Tags: oracle, select, oracle11g

I have a select statement written for a table i.e STAY table in which 2 of the date fields namely ADMSN_DT and DSCHRG_DT are not availabe. So I was informed to fetch these fields from another table named CLM table by joining the claim_id.

So I have framed my select query as,

```
select 
Member_id as MemberID,
(select a.ADMSN_DT from CLM a, STAY b where a.cl_id = b.claim_id) as Admission_Date,
(select a.DSCHRG_DT from CLM a, STAY b where a.cl_id = b.claim_id) as Discharge_Date,
field 1,
feild 2, such as ... some fields from STAY table
from STAY;
```

The problem here is I got a 2 records from this table, the claim_id is different but I get the same date in both the record.

For Eg:-

```
Claim_id    Admission_date   Discharge_date
1234         11/12/2015        12/12/2015          -- this claim id has dates in clm table
5678         11/12/2015        12/12/2015          -- this claim id has no dates in clm table
```

its just copying the same value from first record to the second record.. HOw to avoid this? Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following query;

`select Member_id as MemberID,
    (select a.ADMSN_DT from CLM a where a.cl_id = s.claim_id) as  Admission_Date,
    (select a.DSCHRG_DT from CLM a  where a.cl_id = s.claim_id) as Discharge_Date
from STAY s;`

Answer (score 1):

Your code makes cartesian product between result of sub query and other results returning from the enclosing query

try this :

`select 
Member_id as MemberID,
a.ADMSN_DT  as Admission_Date,
a.DSCHRG_DT as Discharge_Date,
field 1,
feild 2,  ... 
from STAY b, CLM a
where a.cl_id = b.claim_id(+)`